# Back Button to go another Activity not parent Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, back, onbackpressed

I created a back button with this code

```
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

So that the user comes back to the parent Activity.
But now I want that the user comes back to  another Activity (not the parent activity). How can I do that ?

Comment: did you check out the answer..

Comment: But it's not a good design to redirect user to another page when they click back button.The back button should redirect user to previous page .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle actionbar home button pressed event and performed your logic

```
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                      // Your desired class
                       startActivity(new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class)); 
                    break;
                }
                return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to override `onBackPressed()` from your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    startActivity(new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    finish();

}
```

> **Note :**  In this code `ThisActivity` is your current Activity and `NextActivity` is which you open Activity on Back Button Click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:

                Intent about = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Target.class);;
                startActivity(about);
                finish();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

> here `android.R.id.home` refer to your Back icon which is in `ActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in manifest, for your activity name modify it

```
        <activity
            android:name="SecondActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="ParentActivity" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.app_name.A" />
        </activity>
```

Then you should add code like below in your Child or Second Activity no need to pass intent just `finish()` current activity like below

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:

                    Intent intent = new     Intent(SecondActivity.this,ParentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(about);
                    finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```